# hide specific child element from an html using prototype

Tags: prototypejs, prototype

using prototype, I am trying to hide the specific children element of a particular element.

From the html below, I want to hide child `ul` and all of its element:

```
<ul>
   <li id="category_1" class="active">
   <strong id="img_1" class="cat_plus"></strong>
   <input type="checkbox" name="cat_id[]" value="1">
       <ul>
           <li id="category_3">
               <strong id="img_1" class="cat_plus"></strong>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cat_id[]" value="3">Root Catalog
           </li>
        </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

i tried:

```
$('category_1 ul').hide();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
$$('#category_1 ul').first().hide();
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ayATt/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: TypeError: $$(...).first(...) is undefined